# Migrating from SQL Server to Hive Table using flat file

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive

I am migrating my data from SQL Server to Hive using following steps but there is data issue with the resulting table. I tried various options including checking datatype, Using `csvSerde` but not able to get data aligned properly in respective columns. I followed following steps:

1. Export SQL Server data to flat file with fields separated by comma.
2. Create external table in Hive as given below and load data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myschema.mytable (
r_date timestamp
, v_nbr varchar(12)
, d_account int
, d_amount decimal(19,4)
, a_account varchar(14)
) 
row format delimited 
fields terminated by ',' 
stored as textfile;            

LOAD DATA INPATH 'gs://mybucket/myschema.db/mytable/mytable.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE myschema.mytable;
```

There is issue with data with all combination I could try.
I also tried OpenCSVSerde but the result was worse than simple text file. I also tried by changing delimiter to semicolon but no luck.

```
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
with serdeproperties ( "separatorChar" = ",")  stored as textfile
  location 'gs://mybucket/myschema.db/mytable/';
```

Can you please suggest some robust approach so that I don't have to deal with data issue.
Note: Currently I don't have option of connecting my SQL Server table with Sqoop.

Comment: What is `gs` in your file paths? What is the actual problem here? That the columns are not being aligned correctly? Can you show us an example record? How does it look? How is it supposed to look? What tools do you have available to you? Do you have access to Spark in your infrastructure?

Comment: This issue was related to finding correct delimiter. As data contained both , and ; in data field. So I had to go with a predifined delimeter that was some character.